# can we use Zend_Form_Element_Image for show image from database

Tags: php, zend-framework

hi 
I have some jpg images in MySQL table. 
can we show these images with Zend_Form_Element_Image
Could someone please help me by providing sample code?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry i can't provide a working example but here are some useful infos straight from the [docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html).

**Zend_Form_Element_Image**

Image elements use the [Image Decorator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html#zend.form.standardDecorators.image) for rendering, in addition to the standard Errors, HtmlTag, and Label decorators.

**Zend_Form_Decorator_Image**

By default, the decorator uses the element's src property, which can be set with the `setImage()` method, as the image source.

====

As i understand, first you need to set up an url (controller) which displaying the image from the db then you can add this url as a parameter to `setImage()`